# Codeigniter error Unable to load the requested file 0.php but theres no such file

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and it is throwing the error: *unable to load the requested file 0.php*

But there's no such file! I don't understand why its doing this?

As a result of this error, the homepage of my site has vanished. All the other pages are accessible and work except for the homepage.

I don't know where I'm supposed to look, whether its the view files or the controller files?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: add your home page controller and view code

Comment: Are you generating views programmatically? chance you pass a 0 instead of a string?

Comment: @kumar_v in the controllers folder I cant see a file for the homepage.

Comment: check your applications / config /route.php for default controller

Answer (score 0):

- Go in your */application/config/routes.php* & check parameters for
  `$route['default_controller']`
- Go to */application/controllers* & check if the file defined in
  routes really exists?
- If yes, check `public function index()` in that you might have loaded
  models & views that does not really exist

If this won't solve your issue, post your structure of application, model & view folder and routes.php file.